# How to sum if we use substring function

Tags: xslt

I want to ask how to get total amount if we use substring function,
for example I have this xml,

```
<document>

    <line id="0">
        <field id="0"><![CDATA[AAAddd17aaass]]></field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="0"><![CDATA[DDDaaa33sssaa]]></field>
    </line>
</document>
```

I should sum(substring(field[@id='0'], 7,2)). Then I try to do that, I get this error message: Current Item is 'NaN of type xs:string. (I try to use number function but it doesn't help)

Please advice me how to solve it.

Comment: Dosent help means? it it an error or is it not summing them up?

Comment: The errors are the same, only instead of 'xs:string' wrote xs:double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In XSLT 1.0 if you don't want to write recursive templates yourself, you can use the [`transform-and-sum`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/transform-and-sum.xsl?revision=1.1&view=markup) template from [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)**.

See how to use it **[here](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200111/msg00835.html)**.

---

**Here is the full transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:func-transform="f:func-transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f func-transform"
>
   <xsl:import href="transform-and-sum.xsl"/>

   <!-- to be applied on testTransform-and-sum.xml -->

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <func-transform:func-transform/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="transform-and-sum">
        <xsl:with-param name="pFuncTransform"
                        select="document('')/*/func-transform:*[1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="/*/*/*"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="func-transform:*" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:param name="arg1" select="0"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="number(substring($arg1, 7,2))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<document>
    <line id="0">
        <field id="0"><![CDATA[AAAddd17aaass]]></field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="0"><![CDATA[DDDaaa33sssaa]]></field>
    </line>
</document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
50
```

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: How to change in my case this line:  <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="/*/*"/> of yours code?

Comment: @Petras: This will be: `/*/line[id='0']/field[id='0']`

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I get answer NaN. Maybe I'm download bad templates from your's taken websites. I'm using to execute this program cooktop and xalan-2 engine. Download fxsl-Xalan-1.1.zip.

Comment: @Petras: The Xalan and MSXML edition of FXSL 1.x are older and I stopped supporting them years ago. My guess is that for the Xalan edition of this example to work you must drop the `mode="f:FXSL"` from the template.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I solve it, without transform-and-sum.xsl ,but yours example help me to finish it.

Answer (score 2):

Easy in XSLT 2.0:

```
sum(field[@id='0']/number(substring(., 7,2)))
```

Rather more difficult in XSLT 1.0: see for example http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t170401-sum-over-computed-value.html

Comment: Still not that difficult. It's one rec function, which is how you think of sum anyway, and it's how you'd do it in any other language like SML (or Haskell, for the trendy).

Comment: @Nicholas, you think of sum as a recursive function? only in a language where recursion is the default. Most people coming to XSLT for their XML processing needs don't have the kind of language background to find writing recursive functions easy.

Comment: +1. Or to put it another way, `sum(for $item in field[@id='0'] return
number(substring($item, 7,2)))`, which might be easier notation to understand for some people (like me). @Michael, that is equivalent to your answer, right?

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I am the guy who once implemented the Buchberger algorithm in XSLT (it was all 1.0 back in those days). Recursion is kind of key to XSLT's processing model though.